# R coding to delete repetitive rows at random

Tags: r

I have a data set labelled merge, which has a couple of different headings, the two main headings are idnumber1 and idnumber2 for example:

```
idnumber 1           idnumber2     agegroup     gender
234700                46016         15            1
234700                46014         15            1
223914                46016         15            1
223914                46014         15            1
227296                46016         15            1
227296                46014         15            1
224170                46016         15            1
224170                46014         15            1
233531                46016         15            1
233531                46014         15            1
```

I have over 800000 data records with more variables and this is what I am trying to do:
- Count the number of rows in the data set N

- Starting at row 1 (i=1), does the next row have the same idnumber1? If so, does the next row also, etc until you have counted the number of rows (k) with the same idnumber1
- Select one of these k rows to keep
- Generate a random number (r) between 0 and 1.
- If r<1/k then keep row 1, else if r<2/k then keep row 2, ... else if r<=k/k then keep row k
- Record idnumber2 for the record you are going to keep and delete all other rows in the data set which have the same idnumber2
- Also record the corresponding column data of the selected record
- Starting at row i (the first row for the current idnumber1) and going to the last row with the same agegroup, gender etc check if this row’s idnumber2 is the same as the selected one, if so, delete the row
- Having completed one selection, move on the next idnumber1 (now the second line in the data set) and repeat the whole process

Comment: This question is extremely broad - what do you  have so far? What is not working?

Comment: Please post what you've tried and where exactly it is failing your requirements. This isn't a place where you just write up a spec and someone else programs it for you. We're here to help you learn.

Comment: I am struggling to start as I have a number of idnumber1 which repeat and I want to only keep one and delete everything else that repeats. I know I have to generate a random number but i don't know how. Should I be using the runif command?

Comment: I suggest explaining what you wnat in natural language. Do unique combination of `idnumber1` and `idnumber2` form categories from which you want a single random draw? That is not hard to program, but you need to make a clear problem description. Or are we just suppose to randomly draw one instance from categories of `idnumber1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to randomly keep one row with each value in `idnumber1`. This can be done with split-apply-combine:

```
set.seed(144)
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$idnumber1),
                      function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 1),]))
#        idnumber1 idnumber2 agegroup gender
# 223914    223914     46016       15      1
# 224170    224170     46014       15      1
# 227296    227296     46014       15      1
# 233531    233531     46014       15      1
# 234700    234700     46016       15      1
```